# Why passport.js requires client secret for google oauth2?

Tags: google-oauth, passport.js

When connecting your app with google oauth2 for user's login, you only need to send client_id to identify your apps, callback and few other properties but you don't need to send a client_secret.

example :

```
// Parameters to pass to OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
const params = {
    client_id:
        "692092518182-rjgh0bja6q41dllpq2dptn134cmhiv9h.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080/test.html",
    response_type: "token",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile email",
    include_granted_scopes: "true",
    state: "pass-through value"
};
```

Why does passport.js requires a client secret ?